# use noUISlider with Rails

Tags: jquery, dom, nouislider

I am trying to get noUiSlider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) to work with rails.

I have tried using the gem : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nouislider-rails/8.2.1#Usage

I tried doing it without the gem -->  got the latest version from http://refreshless.com/nouislider/download/. Added the css and the js to the asset pipeline, and updated the application.js and application.css.

Then to use :
in view :

```
<div class="" id="term-slider"></div>
```

in js (inside `$(document).ready(function()`):

```
var slider = $("#term-slider");
noUiSlider.create( slider, {
  start: [20, 80],
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 100
  }
});
```

Tried using the old syntax as well as the new one : http://refreshless.com/nouislider/new-version/

But I am not able to see it. I get this error : `noUiSlider.create requires a single element.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

noUISlider accepts a DOM Element as its first argument, but your call sends it a jQuery element (which is a DOM Element wrapper with some additional properties).

You can obtain the raw DOM Element by either using native calls

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
```

Or extracting the raw element from the jQuery object:

```
var slider = $("#term-slider")[0];
```

The rest of your call can remain unchanged.